# How can I make changes in my LSTM model to predict better

Tags: lstm

I have a time series dataset of temperature measurements spanning from 2019 to 2023. I've developed an LSTM model with the goal of predicting future temperatures. The dataset is split into two parts: the first part is used for training the model, and the second part is used for evaluation.

However, I'm facing challenges with the model's performance as it is not accurately predicting future temperatures. I would greatly appreciate your assistance in identifying any necessary modifications or improvements to enhance the model's performance, allowing it to make more accurate predictions of future temperatures.

this my code:

```py
#### Link to Google Drive and load modules

# generic modules
import datetime, os
import itertools
import time
import pickle

# basic data science modules
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns

# keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# sklearn helper functions
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix

# Import LSTM-related modules
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM


df = pd.read_csv('Master CSV v1.csv',index_col='Date/Time',parse_dates=True)
# Convert 5-minute data to 48-hour data

# Resample the dataframe to 2-hour frequency and take the mean value within each 2-hour interval
df = df.resample('48H').mean()

df = pd.DataFrame(df, index=df.index)

#### inputs and outpts
Y = df['warm well temperature (°C)']

input_columns = ['warm well temperature (°C)']
X = df[input_columns]

# Split the dataset into training and validation sets
Xtra, Xval, Ytra, Yval = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.20, shuffle=False)

# Convert DataFrame to NumPy array
Xtra = Xtra.values
Xval = Xval.values

# Rescale input and output datasets
Sx = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
Sy = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

Xtra = Sx.fit_transform(Xtra.reshape(Xtra.shape[0], -1)) 
Xval = Sx.transform(Xval.reshape(Xval.shape[0], -1)) 

Ytra = Sy.fit_transform(Ytra.values.reshape(-1, 1)) 
Yval = Sy.transform(Yval.values.reshape(-1, 1))

# function for LSTM model

def LSTMmodel(L, D, H):
    i = Input(shape=(L, D), name='input_layer')
    x = LSTM(H, activation='relu', name='recurrent_layer', return_sequences=False)(i)
    x = Dense(1, name='output_layer')(x)
    model = Model(i, x, name='LSTM')
    return model

# Create an instance of the LSTM model
lstm_model = LSTMmodel(L=130, D=1, H=150)

# modelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
modelCheckpoint = ModelCheckpoint('LSTM_model_weights v1.hdf5', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_accuracy',mode='auto', save_weights_only=True)

# Compile and train the LSTM model using the fit function
lstm_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01), metrics=['accuracy'])
r = lstm_model.fit(Xtra, Ytra, epochs=500, validation_data=(Xval, Yval), verbose=0, batch_size=64, callbacks=[modelCheckpoint])

# load best model weights
lstm_model.load_weights('LSTM_model_weights v1.hdf5')

# Function for plotting training history
def plot_training_history(r, figsize=(10, 3)):
    f, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=figsize)

    # Loss
    axes[0].plot(r.history['loss'], label='Training Loss')
    axes[0].plot(r.history['val_loss'], label='Validation Loss')
    axes[0].set_title('Loss Trajectories')
    axes[0].set_xlabel('Epochs')
    axes[0].set_ylabel('Loss')
    axes[0].legend()

    # Accuracy
    axes[1].plot(r.history['accuracy'], label='Training Accuracy')
    axes[1].plot(r.history['val_accuracy'], label='Validation Accuracy')
    axes[1].set_title('Accuracy Trajectories')
    axes[1].set_xlabel('Epochs')
    axes[1].set_ylabel('Accuracy')
    axes[1].legend()

    # Adjust plot
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    return f, axes

# Call the modified function
plot_training_history(r, figsize=(10, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first point to note is that you have selected a **binary_crossentropy** as the loss function - which is used for binary classification problems. As you are working with temperature data, this is not the case here.

Without judgement, it appears as though the LSTM model in this case is being used in a "black-box" fashion - i.e. the model is simply being fed temperature data without any consideration as to the parameters of the model or an understanding of the data itself with respect to aspects such as seasonality, trend, etc.

My first port of call would be to analyse the seasonality in this time series. If you are using a 2-hour frequency, then you should observe a seasonal fluctuation between day and nighttime temperatures. Of course, this will not be consistent across season (e.g. if you are in the Northern Hemisphere, winter daytime temperatures will likely be colder than summer nighttime temperatures).

As an example, here is an example of a fluctuation in temperatures between day and night over a period of just over 8 days (data is hypothetical and created by author for illustration purposes):

[image: temperature]

While the temperature fluctuations from day to night will not be exactly the same as in the theoretical example above, you should see a similar fluctuation.

Now, when generating an autocorrelation function, we can see that the correlation is peaking at 24 time steps (or 24 hours).

```
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as ts
plot_acf(temp, lags=100, zero=False);
plt.savefig("acf.png")
plt.close()
```

[image: acf]

Given that you are using a 2-hour average, then I would expect that a peak in correlation would be evident every 12 lags or so.

Once the seasonality and trend has been established, then you will be in a better position to select the model most appropriate for your forecast. I would recommend ARIMA as a starting point here. You can use [auto_arima](https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/tips_and_tricks.html) to aid in automatically selecting the parameters that best fit the model - but at the same time do a sanity check and make sure it coincides with the observed characteristics of the time series.

If you are using such a model to forecast temperature - then you need to determine how far out you wish to forecast. Building a forecasting model on data with a frequency of 2 hours is likely better suited to forecasting temperature fluctuations for the next week - as it is unlikely that seasonal shifts in temperature would interfere with the forecast.

On the other hand, if your data leads up to the summer months and you would prefer to forecast temperatures in the winter months - then you are better off using data over a longer period, e.g. data measured weekly or monthly.